# Why is HashMap.keyIterator class private?

Tags: java

That class would be so useful to me! Ok, I can copy paste it from the Java SDK files but I still wonder, why are `KeyIterator`, `ValueIterator` and their superclass `HashIterator` private?

Comment: The intention is that all you need is the interface `Iterator`, and you shouldn't care what the underlying imlementation of that interface is.

Comment: Well, I just want my `HashMap` class iterable...

Comment: You can use keySet, values, and entrySet and get iterators from those.

Comment: It might help if you clarified what it is you're trying to do.  You've pointed out what you're stuck on, but not the [original problem that led you to get stuck here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: They're private because they're not supposed to be useful to other people. A HashMap does the things it's supposed to, *and as few other things as possible* - same for every well-designed class.

Comment: Even if they were public, what the heck would you do with them? They wouldn't be compatible with your own class.

Comment: Classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What is the *real* problem you're trying to solve? Using someone else's iterator class for some other implementation isn't going to solve anything.

Comment: @TomášZato - You know about Map.entrySet(), right?   That's perfectly iterable...